# External 24" Monitor Flickers, connected to DVI

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, display

I have a 24" external monitor (HP LP2475w). With my old laptop (PC) this monitor worked perfectly. Now with my new Macbook Pro (10.6.1) this external monitor flickers about every 15-20 seconds. The flicker is extremely fast and seems to just be entirely white. The monitor is connected by DVI-DVI. One important thing to note is that this monitor, when plugged into my old PC, was plugged in via VGA.

Any ideas about how to get the flickering to stop? I've tried using a different mini-display port adapter and a different macbook pro to no effect.

Comment: have you tried plugging it out and in again?

Comment: yup. even tried blowing air in the connection ends like the old nintendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is to change the monitor cable.  Often something like that is due to a marginal cable working on the old configuration, and then a new device is hooked up, and the cable just can't work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Refresh rate?  I would imagine the Mac would set this correctly but it might be worth checking.

Might be worthwhile checking the DVI functionality with another PC as well, just to ensure it works.